# Error accessing LUIS model: 'BadArgument: Enumerable of models is empty'

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I'm trying to access a LUIS App from luis.ai portal but at the top it shows a message saying: 'BadArgument: Enumerable of models is empty'.

All I did before getting that error was creating a new version of the app by cloning it from another version.

I cannot access this LUIS app neither export the App data as JSON file :/

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you use the documenation's ability to call apis -- Open API Testing Console -- found on each api page. Use it to gett app info or delete the clone'd app. https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c37

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I had to create a new LUIS app using the latest version of the JSON file that I had previous to this issue.

And that time, everything did work.